# Pop up menu on Canvas: only display within specific boundary

Tags: java, canvas, swt, popupmenu

I am displaying an `Image` on a `Canvas`. When the user right-clicks on the canvas, a context-menu is displayed.

How do I only display the menu if the user clicked within the bounds of the image? I can get the `x` and `y` position from the event, but surely it is too late at that point!

```
final Menu pixelContextMenu = new Menu(canvas);
canvas.setMenu(pixelContextMenu);

final MenuItem resetImageItem = new MenuItem(pixelContextMenu, SWT.NONE);
resetImageItem.setText("Reset Image");
resetImageItem.addListener(SWT.MenuDetect, new Listener() {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        int x = event.x;
        int y = event.y;
    }
});
```

Comment: Just remove it temporarily and see if it works then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Event#doit` and set it to `false` if the event is outside of your area. Here's an example that'll show the menu on the left half, but not the right half of the `Canvas`:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("Stackoverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(shell, SWT.NONE);

    Menu menu = new Menu(canvas);
    new MenuItem(menu, SWT.NONE).setText("MenuItem");
    canvas.setMenu(menu);

    canvas.addListener(SWT.MenuDetect, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event)
        {
            Point location = canvas.toControl(event.x, event.y);
            if(location.x > canvas.getBounds().width / 2f)
                event.doit = false;
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

---

If you want to show the `Menu` in any case, but disable some menu items based on the event position, then do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("Stackoverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(shell, SWT.NONE);

    Menu menu = new Menu(canvas);
    final MenuItem item = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.NONE);
    item.setText("MenuItem");
    canvas.setMenu(menu);

    canvas.addListener(SWT.MenuDetect, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event)
        {
            Point location = canvas.toControl(event.x, event.y);

            item.setEnabled(location.x <= canvas.getBounds().width / 2f);
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Don't you love it when a library behaves like you expect:)

Comment: Actually, I believe there is an error here, as the event will be executed when user right clicks on the canvas, not when they click the menu item

Comment: @Robben_Ford_Fan_boy Well, this was your question: "I only display the menu if the user clicked within the bounds of the image?". That's what I provided. Anyway, I updated my answer with an alternative. Maybe that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I mean in your example, the listener code executes when the user right clicks the canvas. The expected behaviour would be to right click canvas, get pop-up menu, then select the item, which would execute the listener code.

Comment: @Robben_Ford_Fan_boy Well, then add a selection listened to the `MenuItem` to catch selection events of the item

Comment: That doesn't work. I wonder do I have a competing mouse click listener. Mmmmmm

Comment: @Robben_Ford_Fan_boy In any case, please try to explain in more detail what exactly it is you want and what exactly isn't working as expected.